# Residuals and envelope plot in R

Tags: r, plot, jags

I fitted a regression model using JAGS and now I want to do a simulated envelope of residuals to check the fit of this model. Suppose that the matrix below is the matrix of residuals, where each row is a observation and each column is a simulation.

The first column is the residuals from original dataset and the others are the simulated residuals

```
resid <- matrix(runif(330,0,2),ncol =11)
resid <- apply(resid,2,sort)
```

To do the simulated envelope I need to find the minimum, maximum and mean for each observation without the first column that is the original residuals. Then I did it

```
means <- apply(resid[,-1],1,mean)
minimuns <- apply(resid[,-1],1,min)
maximuns <- apply(resid[,-1],1,max)
```

Now I need to plot as lines each means,minimuns and maximuns against

`z=qnorm((i+n-1/8)/(2*n+1/2))`

In this case `n=30` and `i=1:30`

So what I need to do now is put in a plot the minimums, maximuns and means as lines and then put the points of first column (original data) against `z` too.

How I can do it?

I want do do like in the image below, but with black continous lines.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's a bare-bones plot without a lot of formatting...

**edited**

```
resid <- matrix(runif(330,0,2),ncol =11)
resid <- apply(resid,2,sort)

means <- apply(resid[,-1],1,mean)
minimuns <- apply(resid[,-1],1,min)
maximuns <- apply(resid[,-1],1,max)

n=length(minimuns)
i=seq_along(minimuns)
z=qnorm((i+n-1/8)/(2*n+1/2))

plot(z, minimuns, type='l',ylim=range(c(minimuns,maximuns,resid[,1])))
lines(z, maximuns)
lines(z, means, lty=2)
points(z, resid[,1])
legend("topleft", legend=c("envelope", "mean", "first column"), lty=c(1,2,NA),pch=c(NA,NA,1))
```

Or perhaps something like

```
plot(NA, xlim=range(z), ylim=range(c(minimuns,maximuns,resid[,1])))
polygon(c(z,rev(z)),c(minimuns,rev(maximuns)),border=NA, col="grey90")
lines(z, means, lty=2)
points(z, resid[,1])
```

This can be prettified, of course, but this is one solution that came to my mind.

Comment: It's not working properly, the values of first column and z should be like (z, first column) where z is in x-axis and first column is in y-axis

Comment: am I interpreting correctly then that _everything_ is plotted against z (that is, with z as the respective x-coord)?

Comment: Yes, z is x-coord, I don't know but here is not showing the 30 values in the plot

Comment: edited.  Note that your simulated residual matrix had 33 rows, not 30.

Comment: Yeah, my mistake, shoud have 11 columns, but still showing only 3 points where should be 30

Comment: only showing 3 points using your real data, or the simulated version?

Comment: The lines are maked based only in the simulation, ie, columns 2,3,..,11. The first column is used to do the points in the plot. Since each column have 30 points, the plot should have at least 30 points.

Comment: Agreed.  My plot has 30 points using the data that was generated with the code you provided -- this makes me think that there's something else going on at your end, perhaps masking with other variables.  Try running with a clean workspace.